# How can I see a rescaled image in UV Editor?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

I've been having some troubles when I change the mapping scale of a texture that I'm using as Base Color map in Blender.

In Maya when you change the scale of an image you can see this changes reflected in UV Editor like this:

[image: changing scale to the image]
[image: image tiling]
[image: Uv Editor]
That way you can tile an image (without rescaling the Uvs) and know exactly where you're placing your Uvs
in the texture if you need to make some especific Uvs concur with something in your image.

However, in Blender, when I replicate this process it happens differently:
[image]
[image]

As it's shown I'm only able to see the image with the original mapping scale.
I figured out that this happens because in the UV editor you're seeing the "loaded image", not the "applied image" (which includes the scale changes) so here's my question:

**Is there any way to see the image tiled in the UV Editor, like in Maya example I've uploaded?**

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

To tile/repeat an image in the material using the UV editor, you would need to scale up the UV map and place it manually on the image (the UV map will need to be larger than the bounds of the image). The tiling/repeated-image used as texture will be visible on the 3d viewport in material preview mode or in render preview mode.

[image]

To view the tiled the image in the UV editor. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the editor properties and in the view tab enable **Repeat Image**.

[image]

**Old Answer** (I'll keep it just to reference the comments)

Use a texture coordinate node to set the texture to use UV coordinates.
With a mapping node you can control the location rotation and scale of the texture used.

[image]

Changing the scale will allow you to repeat the texture within the UV coordinates.

Note that when you use Pont as the type, a scale of 5 means that the texture will be repeated 5 times on a given axis.

Also note that the image texture node has to be set to **Repeat**.

[image]

If you choose Texture as Type on the mapping node then you can repeat the texture by using values smaller than 1.0, for example a value of 0.2 will repeat the image texture 5 times.

[image]

The texture can be visualized in the Preview window for the material

[image]

Comment: But it's the same thing I did, except changing the scale from the Image Texture node instead of adding the Texture Coordinate node, which is essentially the same thing. Doing this the image is still not displayed tiled in UV Editor
I appreciate the answer though, but it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: See edited answer